# docker-compose Can't find a suitable configuration file

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose

For anyone that knows about docker on Linux:

I just try to docker-compose a simple docker image, getting this weird error telling me that there is no `docker-compose.yml file` - however the file actually exists. See this asciinema demonstration:

https://asciinema.org/a/rudbq7AKTJBQlGj8LVJHIG7Zx

Comment: Make sure you are using Latin characters in your `docker-compose.yml` filename. For example this one `dοcker-compose.yml` looks fine, but the first `o` is a greek `ο` and fails with the same error.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but this is not the issue in this case - as you can see, this docker-compose.file is deadly simple with regular english letters only.

Comment: Do you see your file when you execute this? copy paste! `find . -name "docker-compose.yml"`

Comment: Yes, just as you can see this asciinema demonstration

Comment: don't you have to specify `version` in `docker-compose.yml` files?

Answer (score 9):

Moving my `docker-compose.yml` files into (children of) `/root` solved the issue for me.

Doing a `docker-compose up` in `/srv/mystuff` resulted in a `Can't find a suitable configuration file...` error, although `/srv/mystuff/docker-compose.yml` existed. Then I did

```
mv /srv/mystuff /root
cd /root/mystuff
docker-compose up
```

It worked. Because apparently:

> All files that `docker` needs access to should live within your `$HOME` folder.

https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/6361#issuecomment-588301001

https://github.com/docker-archive/docker-snap#usage

Comment: I don't think that's the cause, I have a whole bunch of stuff running out of /opt though I am starting to face this issue quite randomly on a particular service.

Answer (score 2):

You did not have include docker-compose version in composer file. Try to define your services properly as follows.

```
version: '3'
services:
  my-test:
   image: hello-world
```

Usefull [link](https://geekdosage.com/how-to-create-a-private-docker-registry-in-ubuntu-20-04/)

Comment: I have version in yml file and still the same error.